# Set a UniformGrid fixed column width

Tags: wpf, xaml, uniformgrid

I was wondering if it's possible to set a fixed cell size (column width, row height), instead setting a fixed number of columns and/or rows, while still having all cells the same size?

Comment: Set the Width of the UniformGrid to a multiple of the cell width, i.e. Width = numColums * columnWidth.

Comment: @clemens makes a good suggestion, you could one step further and wrap that up in a custom iconverter implementation where you bind the grid width to the cell width and pass multiplier as a parameter. Keeps more of the detail in xaml.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to do that just in XAML, resorted to making a custom IValueConverter in the code-behind, since I couldn't do that.

Comment: Is that not essentially a WrapPanel with ItemHeight and ItemWidth set?